# How can I use libraw in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I have installed LibRaw-0.20.1.zip from https://www.libraw.org/download.

I compile it, and produce `libraw.lib` and `libraw.dll`. It is 32 bit.

I then use it in qt:

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../LibRaw-0.20.0/lib/ -llibraw
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../LibRaw-0.20.0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../LibRaw-0.20.0
```

This path is right, but I get this is error:

> C:\QtProject\UDP\mainwindow.cpp:359: error: undefined reference to `LibRaw::LibRaw(unsigned int)'

Comment: What other error messages do you get from your linker? Doesn't it complain about not being able to find "liblibraw.lib" or somesuch?

Comment: What's the deal with the win32 selector?

Comment: I already can run. Thanks.